# Bind city column values in db to view as Dropdownlist using mvc4 and stored procedure

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, stored-procedures, ado.net

In my project City table is there. in my applcation I want city to place as `dropdown list`. I am using `ADO net`. can u please give me some idea how can i use it in controller and bind it to view `@Html.DropDownListFor`

Answer (score 0):

Simplest method to bind dropdownlist in mvc(i m taking hypothetical example here) :-

Controller :

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index()
{
Maplocations obj=new Maplocations();
obj.mapLocationItemTypes = binddropdown();
return View(obj);
}

Public List<SelectListItem> binddropdown()
{
// call stored procedure here and get value for dropdown
}
```

Model(Maplocations) :

```
 public List<SelectListItem> mapLocationItemTypes { get; set; }
 public int mapLocationItemVal { get; set; }
```

View:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.mapLocationItemVal , new SelectList(Model.mapLocationItemTypes , "Value", "Text"), "  -----Select List-----  ")
```

here in above example the 3rd overload of `DropDownListFor()` i.e. `" -----Select List----- "` will be the initial selected item of your dropdown with value equal to  ' '.

At Controller during POST `mapLocationItemVal` will have selected dropdown value.

The above shown code is best and simplest way to bind Dropdownlist in MVC.

Comment: where can i call my stored procedure

Comment: @user3913759..i think above code is enough for your understanding if you need more help then comment..

Comment: I have coding in diffrenr layers. I am getting confusion to take the cities in list

Comment: @user3913759..then how can i understand your situation sitting at my place..just post another question...my answer is more than enough to guide you binding dropdown...thankz...